# Zero-sets and kernels?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question concerning zero-sets.

Is the zero-set of a function the equivalent of the kernel for linear maps?
My thoughts are that it is but I'm not certain.

Thank you!

Comment: A kernel is the zero set of a homomorphism. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense that it is the set of domain values at which the function is $0,$ yes. However, for general functions, these need not be so nice as kernels of linear maps (which will always be subspaces of the domain vector space). In fact, given a set $X,$ we have that **any** subset of $X$ is the zero-set of some function $X\to\Bbb R.$ To see why, let $A\subseteq X.$ How could we define a function $f:X\to\{0,1\}\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $A$ is precisely the zero-set of $f$?

Comment: Well we could do that by sending all the elements in $A$ to $0$ and all of $X \setminus A$ to $1$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Not complicated, but a good foundational idea.

Comment: Cool. Does it make sense to talk about the zero-set of a set of functions/polynomials? My guess is yes. This would be defined as the intersection of the zero-sets of all the functions/polynomials in that set.

Comment: As long as you define your terms in non-conflicting fashion, it shouldn't be a problem.